# trouble with AWS S3 Bucket policty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i've tried to add this policy to my newly created S3 Bucket

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1548665682202",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1548665490985",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::darbazar-invoices-logs",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "fluentd.darbazar.invoices.user"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1548665526321",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::darbazar-invoices-logs",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "testavi.uzir"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

here u can see 2 users, 1 user has full access and 1 user has only 1 Permission, but if i click save, the  Invalid principal in policy warning has returned to my screen
why? i use the Official AWS S3 policy generator to generate this policy and this principal is exist in my IAM

Comment: what is the policy warning message?

Comment: When you want to specify an IAM user using "AWS" in "Principal", the values must be either ARNs, e.g. `"Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name-1"}` or Canonical User IDs.